# DirectX 11 Map deviceContext failed

Tags: visual-studio, directx

I have an application that render a cube and do some other syuff. But unfortunately, when I want to move some vertices with the mouse. I have an error. When I map the vertex buffer, the vertices recorded in another struct array is empty. For testing my application, I just put a map after creating the vertexbuffer in order to see if the debugger show me the real numbers. It fails too. Everything is populated with a 0.00 value (positions, normals, tangents...).What is the problem ?
Here you can find the code.

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
ZeroMemory( &bd, sizeof(bd) );
bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC; //D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT; //D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;// D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bd.ByteWidth = CBSize( sizeof( VERTEX_PNTTB)* NumVertices);
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
bd.CPUAccessFlags =  D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE; // 0; // D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ; //D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE; // 0;
bd.StructureByteStride = 0;
bd.MiscFlags =  0;
//bd.StructureByteStride
//bd.MiscFlags = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
ZeroMemory( &InitData, sizeof(InitData) );
InitData.pSysMem = (void*)vertices; //(void*)(mesh->GetVertexes().data()); //vertices; //(float*)vertices; // (UINT*)vertices;
InitData.SysMemPitch=0;
ID3D11Buffer* vbuff = NULL;
hr = device->CreateBuffer(&bd, &InitData, &vbuff); // &(m->vertexBuffer)); //&m_pVertexBuffer );
//if( FAILED( hr ) )
//  return hr;
//}
m->vertexBuffer = vbuff;


    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    ID3D11Buffer* &buff = vbuff;
    //g_pImmediateContext->CopyResource(buff, mElements[ 0 ]->getElement().model ->Meshes()[selectedMeshIndex]->VertexBuffer());
    hr = g_pImmediateContext->Map( buff, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD ,0, &mappedResource); // D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        VERTEX_PNTTB *vertices = (VERTEX_PNTTB *)mappedResource.pData;
        // Fill vertex buffer
        //vertices[0].position = vertices[0]; // XMFLOAT3(toX0,toY0,0); //-1;//toX0; //-1;//vf1.x; // x0;
        /*for(UINT i=0; i<faces_indices.size(); i++)
        {
            vertices[ faces_indices[i] ].position.x = vertices[faces_indices[i] ].position.x + DirectX::XMFLOAT3(20*dx,20*dy,0).x;
            vertices[ faces_indices[i] ].position.y = vertices[faces_indices[i] ].position.y + DirectX::XMFLOAT3(20*dx,20*dy,0).y;
            vertices[ faces_indices[i] ].position.z = vertices[faces_indices[i] ].position.z + DirectX::XMFLOAT3(20*dx,20*dy,0).z;

        }*/

        //g_pImmediateContext->Unmap( mElements[ 0 ]->getElement().model ->Meshes()[selectedMeshIndex]->VertexBuffer(), 0);
        g_pImmediateContext->Unmap( buff, 0);
    }
```

Comment: `D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD` does what it says it does. It discards the contents of the buffer. Also you shouldn't be reading from memory you haven't mapped with either `D3D11_MAP_READ` or `D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE`. What you should be doing is using `D3D11_MAP_WRITE` and not reading from mapped memory. Instead keep a copy of the vertexes in normal memory, update them there, and then copy the modified vertexes to the mapped buffer. (Or create a staging buffer, update that, and then copy to the vertex buffer.)

Comment: RTFM: [ID3D11DeviceContext::Map()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Generally you don't want to create Vertex Buffer or Index Buffers in CPU-readable memory as it has a major negative performance impact. You'll find it's much better to have static VB/IB and another copy of the data in standard RAM for the CPU to modify.

That said, you *can* create the Direct3D 11 buffer in shared memory by using `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC` and `D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE`. You then call `Map` with `D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE`.

You definitely should **not** use `D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD` which gives you a fresh piece of memory that has no data in it which will overwrite the old data when you call `Unmap`.